# Django annotate, combine multiple related values onto same instance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have a django app with the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class PersonJob(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person_jobs')
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='person_jobs')
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
```

Multiple `Person` instances can hold the same job at once. I have a `Job` queryset and am trying to annotate or through some other method attach the names of each person with that job onto each item in the queryset. I want to be able to loop through the queryset and get those names without doing an additional query for each item. The closest I have gotten is the following:

```
 qs = Job.objects.all().annotate(first_names='person_jobs__person__first_name')
.annotate(last_names='person_jobs__person__last_name')
```

This will store the name on the Job instance as I would like; however, if a job has multiple people in it, the queryset will have multiple copies of the same Job in it, each with the name of one person. Instead, I need there to only ever be one instance of a given Job in the queryset, which holds the names of all people in it. I don't care how the values are combined and stored; a list, delimited char field, or really any other standard data type would be fine.

I'm using Django 2.1 and Postgres 10.3. I would strongly prefer to not use any Postgres specific features.

Comment: Django has a PgSQL specific `ArrayAgg`, although that is, like said, limited to PgSQL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg

Answer (score 5):

You can use either [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) or [StringAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg, StringAgg  


Job.objects.all().annotate(first_names=StringAgg('person_jobs__person__first_name', delimiter=',')

Job.objects.all().annotate(people=ArrayAgg('person_jobs__person__first_name'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ruddra. Is there any way to accomplish this without Postgres specific features?

Comment: as far as I know, there is not any other way to do that. As far as I can read from your question, you are already using Postgres. Is there any issues with that?